# Combine 2 rsync scripts into one by using a generic pattern

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a BASE/ directory in server1 that contains folders in YYYYMMDD format.
Every day a new folder is created for that day and some files are being written into it intraday.

I have two processes running on server2, one runs every 5 mins and tries to rsync last 2 days worth of data from server1:BASE/ and another one runs once a day and tries to rsyncs directories for the current year (using $(date "+%Y*") as a pattern).

I don't want to maintain 2 separate scripts for these tasks.
I wonder if my script can support a pattern parameter, that I can pass to rsync to copy either last 2 days or all directories for the current year. Note that I want the parameter to specify a dates pattern that I can pass to rsync, not a flag that will specify the logic of the code with branching.

Comment: How will you deal with a "every 5 min" script running while the "once a day do all" is still running? Potentially clash?

Comment: I can use a flock to synchronise runs and make one process wait (or fail) when the other one is running.